# In html make one div's width fixed and another div's width should dynamically reduce according to window size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
<div>
 <div id="div1" class="myimg">
 </div>
 <div id="div2" class="detail">
 </div>
</div>
```

My html5 block is as above. I am using media queries for styling it for iphone,ipad,desktop.

I am new to responsive design. I want to implement style so that div1's image size don't get changed and div2's text contains should be shrinked as I reduce width of my browser window.

even if I am trying to give div2 %width and min-width it is comming down the div1. It is not staying beside div2. If someone can guide me how to write this. that will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this can be accomplished pretty easily. Here is an [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/ffFNt/1/).

HTML

```
<div id="div1" class="myimg"></div> 
<div id="div2" class="detail"></div>
```

CSS

```
.detail {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed black
}

.myimg {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed red
}
```

Is this what you were wanting to accomplish?